# OptaPlanner, build a rule that needs to get information from the solution

Tags: optaplanner

Need some ideas on how to build a rule in my task assignment project. Assign workers to tasks, each task has a happen location, want a soft constraint to make a worker's next task be as close as possible to the fulfilled task. But in DRL how can I know which task is the worker's previous task? the information is in the Solution class. An example is greatly appreciated. Is there any OptaPlanner example that I can refer to? for me to know how to get values from Solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [task assigning example](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/taskassigning) in the optaplanner-examples module, which shows how to model such a problem. The main idea is that every task points to the next task and to the previous task or the worker. The worker is the first element of such a chain.
In this example, one of the goals is to minimize the makespan; your soft constraint about location sounds very similar - instead of penalizing for the amount of time required to complete all the tasks by a single worker, it would focus on the distance between locations associated with each task.